# Mage_Checkout_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found on magento

Tags: php, magento

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Checkout_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 132
```

This is my magento site error when i am open front end and also backend. how did i am slove this error plz tel me any one

thanks`enter code here`

Comment: There is no `includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php` file in standard Magento. There's only a `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php`. Please show at least the code around line 132 of your custom file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running Magento in 'compiled modus', but something went wrong. Have a look at `/home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx/includes/config.php`. There are  two `define()` statements in there. Comment them out and try again.

Comment: thank you for your kind replay, but stil i got the following error,

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getControllerInstance() in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php on line 206